# Is there accepted terminology for algebraic structures whose every subalgebra is free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, universal-algebra

Is there accepted terminology for algebraic structures whose every subalgebra is free?

Examples:

- Any free group
- Any vector space
- More generally, any free module over a PID. In fact, this characterizes PID's; given a commutative unital ring $R$, every free $R$-module enjoys the property of interest iff $R$ is a PID.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/157974/varieties-where-every-algebra-is-free) mathoverflow thread. It's a different question, but related.

Comment: One might say "hereditarily free".